# how to color icon selected in bottomNavigationView with gradient color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have bottomNavigationview with some icon and I want when anyone selected icon , color of the icon changed to gradient color .

gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#ee5f8a"
        android:endColor="#ed8f6d"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

BottomNavigationview

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:itemIconSize="35dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" 
      android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#c2bdbf" />

</selector>
```

Comment: where is the usage of gradient xml

Comment: I didn't use it because i don't know where i can use it .

Comment: show your menu file

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_group"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_supervisor_account_black_24dp"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
       />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        />

</menu>

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to `BottomNavigationView`

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_selector"
```

Create one drawable named `bottom_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ff0000"/>
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This is not a gradient color, however, it is a good solution for solid colors.

Comment: @Hatzil I didn't see that gradient part, however you can use gradient drawable to achieve that. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a drawable selector and not a color selector to create a gradient background.

drawable/selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

drawable/gradient.xml  (same as question)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#ee5f8a"
        android:endColor="#ed8f6d"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

and finally your view

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:itemIconSize="35dp"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Comment: where he said about background color ? the question is how to color icons